# Problema con acentos y ñ en consola de window

Tags: java

Hola buenas estoy empezando con Java y una de las tareas que mandó en profesor fue hacer un programa compilarlo con la consola y que ese lance un mensaje, todo funciona bien excepto que en mi consola no se pintan bien las palabras acentuadas 
Porque pasa esto?

Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Java por defecto, como otros lenguajes, no admiten ni Ñ ni acentos ( caracteres especiales). Y por eso la consola no lo reconoce. Para solucionarlo tendrías que utilizar Unicode e informarte un poco sobre el tema.

Comment: lo unico que quiero es que se muestren de forma correcta al lanzarlo en la consola

Comment: Que yo sepa en java todo es Unicode, es decir si acepta acentos, el problema aquí parece ser la consola que estas usando, no parece ser el símbolo del sistema.